# how to set up nginx aliases on a localhost development server?

Tags: nginx, localhost, alias

Struggling to adapt nginx to my framework and get the equivalent of, in apache config :

```
Alias /site1  "/home/framework/public_HTML"
```

(and then localhost/site1 displays site1 with local/dev settings thanks to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`)

What I have now with nginx :

```
server {

 listen localhost:80;

 server_name localhost;

 root /home/framework;
 index /public_HTML/index.php;

 location /site1 {

    # alias /home/framework/public_HTML/;
    # index index.php;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
    # try_files /home/framework/public_HTML/index.php =404; 

 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
 }
 location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
 }
}
```

-> whether I comment in or out the lines in location /site1, all or none, adding removing trailing slash all around... => transparent redirect to localhost/site1/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/  (as copied from the url in the browser)

So, with everything commented out as it is shown, the correct index.php is getting the request & i'm getting a response but the url in the url bar and the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` passed by nginx to my index.php file becomes

```
 /site1/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/
```

Why this loop ?